# Exploiting an Open Redirect in POST body?

Tags: exploit, phishing, url-redirection

I have the following example POST request as part of a feedback form for a website that allows for an arbitrary value to be supplied to the "done_url" parameter, allowing for an open redirect after the feedback form has been processed.

```
POST /cgi-bin/formproc2.cgi HTTP/1.1
Host: foobar.com

mail_to=support%40support.com&subject=Feedback+Form&done_url=http://phishingsite.com&feedback=I+love+your+site&Submit=Submit
```

I am familiar with the typical forms of phishing done for open redirects in GET requests, such as this example http://www.secureworks.com/resources/blog/research/spam-government-websites-abused-ongoing-spam-campaign/

But how would an attacker exploit this redirect in the POST body?

Comment: I doubt that you could exploit it just as is. Probably you would need to chain it with some other bugs, something like DOM Clobbering (I'm thinking about possible dom clobbering attack in `bb` tags (used on blogs / forums / ....)) (if you could use `name` / `id` attribute too) & bypassing some URL fitlers on that site (so you cannot just insert arbitrary URL in `[url]` bb tag: `[url="any_url"]clickme[/url]`). Imho no general solution possible here, so you'll need to be very case speicific.

Comment: E.g. if that application is using PHP and `$_REQUEST` is used instead of `$_GET` / `$_POST`, then you could convert that attack to GET and make it easily exploitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you would need to have this in a GET for it to be exploitable (in the sense of being able to redirect the user to an arbitrary URL after they've visited the link), however a couple of points occur about this

- It might be possible to convert the POST to a GET and still have it process correctly, depends on the server-side logic.
- That form may well have another issue which is that the target of the main is specified as a parameter.  If an attacker can modify that parameter then they can use this form to send spam to arbitrary addresses.  From a security standpoint the mail_to parameter should be held server-side not sent from the client (if it has to be sent from the client it should be white-list validated before the e-mail is actually sent)

Comment: Rory- you're completely correct. The only foreseeable method that this could be used as Phishing open redirect would be if it could be converted to a GET request, since the whole premise of the phishing attack relies on the victim seeing & trusting the link, and the hostname in the URL.